# IIS and Reverse Proxy with Authentification

Tags: iis, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I'm using IIS7 with URLRewrite and Application Request Routing (ARR) as a reverse proxy. So I can point all requests from `http://localhost/external` to `http://external/external`

This is all working fine in my development set up. However on the client site they have a proxy between the web server and the internet (I'll refer to this as the middle proxy).

I've set up the proxy details for ARR, but the middle proxy requires authentification, so any requests are met with:

```
'http error', 407, 'Proxy Authentication Required'
```

I presume I need to grant the Application Pool user (of the site using URLRewrite/ARR) access to the internet on the middle proxy? Is this the best approach to take, and if so which account should be used? There don't seem to be any ARR options to add a username/password.

*Note this was posted 2 years ago on ServerFault without response, I have now deleted the original which was at -* https://serverfault.com/questions/289083/iis-and-reverse-proxy-with-authentification

Comment: Also there are various posts on meta suggesting the original post should be deleted if posted on another SE site..so not sure if this should be done

Comment: I suggest doing the solution you proposed, which I believe is correct. My experience with credentialed proxies and IIS7 lead me to this. Try doing an after-hour test and/or test with a dev online host isolated via ACL.

Comment: Thanks Lizz. I've tried setting the AppPool user to various different accounts that have access/rights to go through the proxy but this makes no difference.

Comment: Odd... What about credentialing the IIS service itself?

Comment: I'm now wondering i the initial user credentials are simply forwarded by ARR.

Comment: You know if I had a brain while reading your question I might have been the one to suggest temp bypass of ARR. +1! Yes, try that. :) <sigh, not being helpful/objective -sorry>